# 'Modern' Introduction to or Summary of SUSY and BSM?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model

The title really says it all. I am looking for a (preferably friendly and compact) modern introductory text on supersymmetry (SUSY) and beyond-the-standard-model (BSM) particle physics.

As a little bit of background, I am a first-year graduate student working on experimental particle physics (ATLAS). I have some exposure to quantum field theory (Mandl & Shaw, a little bit of Schwartz) and am reasonably comfortable with standard-model particle physics (Halzen & Martin, Thomson).

Most of the materials that come up when I search for such books in SUSY and/or BSM seem too mathematical and/or outdated (some written by some of the first developers of the concept). Despite not finding definitive SUSY signatures yet, particle physics has achieved a lot since the first theoretical development of SUSY, and I am somewhat surprised that it is so difficult to find a nice modern summary of the theory and it status.

So, to sum up: I am looking for study material for introduction to SUSY and BSM. In particular, if I were to be picky, I would prefer it is was (a) relatively modern, (b) not too mathematical/theoretical, but more emphasis on phenomenology and searches for them in experiments, and (c) gives some perspectives on the current status of SUSY.

Any recommendation?

Comment: Do you search material on supersymmetry phenomenology? Or an introduction to the theory? If the latter, then older material is still perfectly fine as not much has changed as far as an introduction goes (well perhaps in the gravity sector but again for an introduction…). Moreover throwing BSM in there is another question altogether as we would get into extra-dimensions e.g. which has a whole separate branch of theories.

Comment: Anyway, circa 2000, I did learn the theory from Martin F. Sohnius, Introducing supersymmetry, Physics Reports 128 (1985), 39 - 204. As for the phenomenology, obviously, you need to read articles post LHC start.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Thank you for the note. And yes, I was hoping to find one that has more emphasis towards phenomenology and experimental searches---hence, the difficulty. Thanks again.

Comment: For a reasonably up-to-date review of phenomenology, the PDG is always a good starting point.